# If, during I'tikaf, I have to do remote work (for my job) for an hour due to a work-emergency, will it invalidate my I'tikaf?

Tags: ramadan, ibadah

If I do I'tikaf and during I'tikaf, an emergency situation arises at my work which can not be resolved without me doing some worldly work, will working (like software development) for a couple of hours **remotely from my computer, without leaving my quarters** invalidate my I'tikaf?

Currently, there is no replacement available at my work to do the work I'll be required to do, and I'll only get leave from work on the condition that I agree to do the required work for a few hours during those days, if a work-emergency situation arises.

There are like 20% to 30% chances that such an emergency situation will arise. But I really want to do I'tikaf?

Is there any related or similar example from the time of Holy Prophet (peace be upon him)?

Comment: 'Itikaf must be performed in a mosque, and this requires you to stay in the mosque and not leave it unless there's a reasonable necessity that requires you to leave. Do you need to leave the mosque for this purpose?

Comment: @Medi1Saif No I will not require to leave the mosque. I'll just need to do some worldly work (work related software setup that only I can do) remotely on my laptop for an hour or so, if the utmost need arises, which most probably won't.